# Allow Wallet access on lock screen "only" when the device is unlocked

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

When using the Apple Wallet app shortcut from the lock screen (double press the home button to bring Wallet up), I noticed that it was possible to bring up the Wallet even when the device is locked. This means that any cards added to Apple Wallet can be seen even if the device is locked.

Is it possible to either hide these cards or to prevent the shortcut from working, when the device is locked? This shortcut is very useful in situations when accessing the Wallet is necessary (and it's useful to be able to quickly get to all the passes), but I do not want anyone else to access my ID cards and/or travel information if they have access to my device while it's locked.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone running iOS 11:

1. Go to Setting app → Touch ID & Passcode.
2. Scroll down to **Allow Access When Locked** section.
3. Turn off the switch against Wallet.

[image]

This will disable Wallet access when the device is locked.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there would be a way to hide the cards or something similar when activated while unlocked, instead of completely removing the shortcut

Comment: I see there is an option *for some cards* to enable/disable "showing on the lock screen"; however, they seem to be referring the automatic showing of cards, rather than whether they will show up at all on the lock screen